# Accessing Draw Context in Dispather timer gives exception

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, drawingcontext

what i am trying to do is first find the angle of the shoulder joint till now i have managed to do that.what i wanted to do now is  when the angle comes in the range  between 70 and 90  a time starts  for 3 sec and in each sec it should check whether the angle is still in the range if it is  then show on screen ok otherwise  restart the timer after displaying the message you have no completed the time limit
Please please em very new to wold of  C# and kinect  any help in this regard will b helpful
the link to an image  of a problem em facing is:
http://i46.tinypic.com/2nu4ygw.jpg

Please help!!

```
       System.Windows.Point shoul_l = this.point_toScreen(sh_left.Position, sen);
        draw.DrawText(new FormattedText(angle.ToString("0"), new 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us"),
          System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
         new Typeface("Verdana"), 16,System.Windows.Media.Brushes.OrangeRed),
         new System.Windows.Point(shoul_l.X+10, shoul_l.Y +20));

        if (timer_start == false)
        {
        if (angle > 70 && angle < 90)
        {
                timer_start = true;
                timer.Interval = 2000;
                timer.Start();
                timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) =>   \    
                on_time_event(sender, e, draw,shoul_l));

        }
        }


}   
void on_time_event(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e, DrawingContext dcrt, 

 System.Windows.Point Shoudery_lefty)
 {
     --index;
     if (index != 0)
     {
         dcrt.DrawText(new FormattedText(index.ToString(), new   
      System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us"),
           System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
          new Typeface("Verdana"), 16, System.Windows.Media.Brushes.OrangeRed),
          new System.Windows.Point(Shoudery_lefty.X+50,Shoudery_lefty.Y+50));
      //  MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
     }
     else
     {
         timer.Stop();
     }
   }
```

i get an exception in this part of the code

```
      dcrt.DrawText(new FormattedText(index.ToString(), new   
      System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us"),
      System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
      new Typeface("Verdana"), 16, System.Windows.Media.Brushes.OrangeRed),
      new System.Windows.Point(Shoudery_lefty.X+50,Shoudery_lefty.Y+50));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to update a UI element from a [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) thread. This is not allowed.
You have to marshal the UI update call to the UI thread using the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) like this:

```
dcrt.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => 
    {
        dcrt.DrawText(new FormattedText(index.ToString(), new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us"),
       System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
      new Typeface("Verdana"), 16, System.Windows.Media.Brushes.OrangeRed),
      new System.Windows.Point(Shoudery_lefty.X+50,Shoudery_lefty.Y+50));
    }));
```

Comment: i tried to replace your code with mine and it says Dispatcher  and Dispatcher priority doesn't exist in current context 
decalring the new instance will not help the cause  ... any help?? @khellang

Comment: The `DrawingContext` derives from `DispatcherObject` which has `Dispatcher` as a property. Try `dcrt.Dispatcher.Invoke(...);`

Comment: You may also need to add a using statement: `using System.Windows.Threading;`

Comment: i know it might get irritating for u but there is still one more problem
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type
"ignore"  has this error

Comment: Really appreciated your help  Thank you so much but it didn't work for me
same old problem  exception at run time... this is the image 

http://i48.tinypic.com/vzzrqo.jpg

Comment: can i return a  integer  value from a  this event handler?
and  how can i get it at the calling end 
can i do like this
int a  = timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) =>   \    
                on_time_event(sender, e, draw,shoul_l));

i tried to do this but it gave me error how can i get the value returned from event handler